# How do I make a line break in python (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x

So I was going to make a board for TicTacToe but I forgot how to do a line break. I think its \n?

```
board = [" ", " ", " " \n, " ", " ", " " \n, " ", " ", " "]
print(board)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the newline character (`\n`) inside the quotes:

```
board = [" ", " ", " \n", " ", " ", " \n", " ", " ", " "]
print(board)
```